# Unmount (or "eject") specific components from an Android device programmatically?

Tags: android

How can I unmount (or "eject") specific components (such as camera, speaker or display) from an Android device programmatically? The same way I unmount an SD card for example.

I didn't find anything on the Web for this.

Comment: You can't.  Mounting/unmounting is a file system concept, it works for SD cards because they're part of the filesystem.  If you have root you could possibly turn off their drivers or something like that, but unmounting is not a generic idea for hardware.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks. How can I turn off their drivers?